# Spam filter is unlocking users clicking on Devise lockable email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

We have a rails application that uses Devise for authentication with the lockable module (with both time and email unlock strategies).

From time to time a user complains that they received an error message on invalid token after clicking on the unlock link in the email. We just now realized that these users (and only them) can try out as many wrong password messages as they want and then still be able to log in when they find out their password again.

As this nullifies the security brought by the lockable module we investigated it further and it seems that at some point before the unlock email reaches their inbox, "something" (spam filter?) clicks on all links in the email and thus unlocks the user without him knowing.

We have tried to find best practices on how to handle this situation and could not find any relevant to this situation (only for unsubscribe emails).

The solutions we are considering are:

- Removing the email unlock strategy
- Overriding Devise to add a confirmation step with a POST to unlock the user
- Overriding Devise to force user to redefine their password once they have been locked

What would be the best practice in this situation to preserve both the security of the application and the user experience ?

Comment: Does it mean that you also need to remove "confirmable" option (if you have it)? If the spam filter clicks all links in all emails the account will be confirmed anyway. Let alone potential phishing attacks. It's clearly not how emails supposed to work and hardly a reason to reconsider your auth logic, especially if it occurs for only one user.

Comment: We do not have the confirmable option but indeed if we had it would have caused problem too. Sadly it's not for only one user but for several. I agree that reconsidering our auth logic due to poor spam filter design is not the best option but if we leave it like that the users with such spam filters would have their accounts more susceptible to dictionary attacks wouldn't they?